# How can I determine whether a window from another application is visible?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, pinvoke

I recently obtained a license for WinX DVD Ripper Platinum, and am annoyed by the fact that, when it's done ripping a DVD, it doesn't tell me so. There's no popup, no system "beep"- nothing. The progress dialog simply closes. The main window doesn't even focus itself...

To speed up my DVD-ripping proccess, I'm making a simple console application (using C# and VS2010) that:

1. Finds the handle of the process named "WinX_DVD_Ripper_Platinum" (the process name of the WinX DVD Ripper Platinum software)
2. Finds the handle of the progress dialog on that process using the `GetChildWindows` method defined in [this sample at pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.enumchildwindows)
3. Starts a `System.Timers.Timer` instance that checks (or is supposed to check) whether the progress dialog has closed every 5 seconds (using [the `GetWindowLong` function](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getwindowlong), and
4. Plays a few beeps with the `System.Console.Beep` method to tell the user that the rip is complete. The timer auto-resets, performing the check (or repeating the beep if the dialog has closed) every 5 seconds until the user presses a key in the console window.

Steps 1, 2, and 4 are working fine, but I'm having problems with step 3- this, my question is, which of the [window style constants](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getwindowlong) should I use to check if the window is visible? (WS_VISIBLE did NOT work...)

For more details, this is the function I'm using to check the dialog's visibility:

```
private static bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    var style = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL.GWL_EXSTYLE);
    var visible = style & (WS flag goes here);
    return visible != 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using [IsWindowVisible()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead?

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid...
:) Thanks for the quick and simple answer. I think I've googled variations of "pinvoke window visible" about 50 times in the last 2 days and somehow never seen that function. Thanks, Lambert.

Comment: Glad it helped! :)  (Edit: By the way, from experience: **never** google "pinvoke" unless you want articles on using `DllImport`!)